# Script for counting total pages on website

Tags: json, api, google-analytics

I am trying to write a script that will check our website everyday for the total amount of web pages we have.  How can I do this using an API like Google Analytics?  Using JSON would be nice.  So here is what it might look like and maybe someone can help please?

```
    {
 "startDate": "{date.startOfMonth.format()}",
 "endDate": "{date.today}",
 "dimensions": ["query","page"]
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can check for the total number of pages you have (which I would assume would include those with and without GA tracking code). You can only check, with GA, the total number of pages that have the tracking code and were visited within a specific date range.

Comment: what about new pages within a specific date range ?

Comment: As long as there's valid GA tracking code on the pages, then they're going to be tracked. Note that data doesn't get updated to your reports until after it's been processed, which could take up to 24 hours.

Answer (score 0):

As nyuen has pointed out you cannot count every page in your web presence with Google Analytics. GA will only register pages that a) have GA tracking code and b) have executed this tracking code at least once in your selected  timeframe. Usually that's most of the pages, but you can't be sure.

What you can do is issuing a query that queries the page path dimension and at least one metric - pageviews would be obvious. That's not because you actually need the number of pageviews for your purpose, but because a query without at least one metric will not work. Send the query via the API or the [query explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/) and then simply count the number of rows in the result set. Since the page path is unique the number of results is the number of distinct pages with pageviews in the selected timeframe, which is the closes you will get with GA.

But there are actually tools for what you are trying to do, so you might want to start with those - for example you might have your script make a system call (assuming a linux system) to [wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html) with the --spider option which will create a list of files on a given domain. This does not require tracking code (it works by following links in the pages source code). There is also web spider software like Screaming frog on Windows (doesn't really work in a script, but I guess Windows has some task scheduling tool that allow you to start programs at pre-defined times) which does not only do the counting but also returns information about the health of your site (dead links etc).

Or, since this seems to be your server, you might write a script that traverses the file system and makes a list of the files it encounters there (will not work if your pages are dynamically generated, since this counts only physical files).

Or you write a script that parses your server logs and extracts call to content files (will work only for files that have actually been viewed).

So there are a number of better alternatives to using Google Analytics for that purpose, you might want to look into one of them first.